# Entropy maximization unbounded/infeasible using CVXPY

Tags: mathematical-optimization, entropy, cvx, cvxpy

I am attempting to solve an entropy maximization problem numerically using CVXPY. Even though the problem passes the [DCP](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/dcp/index.html) checks, I keep getting an infinite result, and problem statuses like infeasible and unbounded_inaccurate (depending on the values I choose for the parameters). I manage to solve the same problem using a nonlinear constrained optimizer like Alabama in R. Below is a small example that reproduces the problem.

```
import cvxpy as cvx

vals = array([  750.,   770.,   790.,   810.,   830.,   850.,   870.,   890.,
         910.,   930.,   950.,   970.,   990.,  1010.,  1030.,  1050.,
        1070.,  1090.,  1110.,  1130.])

n = size(freq)
z = cvx.Variable(2,n)

a = cvx.Parameter(sign="positive", value=989.)
b = cvx.Parameter(sign="positive", value=.1) 
d = cvx.Parameter(sign="positive", value=10.)

obj = cvx.Maximize(cvx.sum_entries(cvx.entr(z)))

cons = []
cons += [ z >= 0., cvx.sum_entries(z) == 1, cvx.sum_entries(z, axis=0) * vals == a ] 

for i in range(n):
    cons += [ cvx.logistic(b*(vals[i] - a - d)) * z[1,i] == cvx.exp(b*(vals[i] - a - d)) * (z[0,i] + z[1,i]) ]

prob = cvx.Problem(obj, cons)
prob.solve(solver=cvx.SCS)
```

I don't quite understand why CVX is having a harder time to solve this problem than other algorithms that are not designed for convex programming problems. Have I overlooked something in the way I have written the constraints?

*** EDIT ***

Having received no answer so far, I will also ask this question on the [CVXPY Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/cvxpy). I will update this thread accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. The solution was to store the numeric value of the logit distribution using Numpy functions and then use its components in the constraints:

```
qre = np.exp(b.value*(vals - a - d.value))/(1.+np.exp(b.value*(vals - a - d.value)))
...
cons += [ qre[i] * (z[0,i]+z[1,i])   ==  z[1,i] ]
```